# git push to remote: commits are going through but can't see files?

Tags: git, ubuntu

i have set up a bare repo on a remote server and can push to it but i am not seeing any files on the remote when i'm finished.... this is what I'm seeing when i push:

```
my-macbook-pro:myapp me$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   www/index.php
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
my-macbook-pro:myapp me$ git add .
my-macbook-pro:myapp me$ git commit -m 'test'
[master 57e4b86] test
 1 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
my-macbook-pro:myapp me$ git push
me@myapp.com's password: 
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 368 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://me@myapp.com:1111/var/www/myapp.git
   ce07e61..57e4b86  master -> master
my-macbook-pro:myapp me$
```

when i ssh in, the files i've "pushed" are not there. any ideas?

Comment: Bare repo says it all. By definition there are no "files" to see - only references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to see files, you're supposed to see revisions. Besides, you have a bare repository on remote which doesn't have a working directory at all.

You can do something like `git branch`, `git show master`, `git log` and some such to examine repository content.

Comment: so i guess i'm not understanding how to set up git to push files to a shared remote server... do you have any tutorials to recommend?

Comment: I have no links other than http://git-scm.com/ and I've learned git by trial and error, but basically you *do* push stuff to a shared remote server just fine. You can pull from it (try `git clone ssh://me@myapp.com:1111/var/www/myapp.git`) too. You can check it out locally on the server by cloning the repository or by pointing the `GIT_DIR` (I think) to it, but you should not expect your original files in the repository itself.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned by Krelin and Ray, a bare repository will not contain the files themselves.  This is a feature, not a bug, as it avoids potential confusion down-the-road.  However, this feature makes a simple push unusable if, for example, you want to update your website on a server.

One solution is to push to a repository on your server and then use hooks to automatically update the files in the target folder.  Digital Ocean has a nice tutorial explaining how to do his here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps

Answer (score 0):

A bare repository is a repository that doesn't have a working directory. You can tell it because what would "normally" be inside the .git folder is right there in the directory, and the directory itself is named with a ".git" suffix.

The point of that is, you wouldn't want to overwrite somebody's changes by pushing into a working directory they're working in. So you have a central check-in repository that everyone shares their changes to that is bare--a repo only, no working directory. Eliminates any risk of that.

Comment: What if it is not a bare repository. I push and yet the files don't show up (Though no error on the Push)?